# XSLT transforming name value pairs to its corresponding XML

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT I am trying to transform a name value pair to its corresponding XML. This feature is primarily used in case of special extensions to a standard. 
The file I want to transform is the following. There are no spaces expected in any of the `extNames`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extensionItems xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ExtensionItems.xsd">
<extensionsItem>
<extName> callCode</extName>
<extValue>1</extValue>
<extType>integer</extType>
</extensionsItem>
<extensionsItem>
<extName>callbackType</extName>
<extValue>All</extValue>
<extType>string</extType>
</extensionsItem>
<extensionsItem>
<extName>callbackEmail</extName>
<extValue>me@mine.org</extValue>
<extType>string</extType>
</extensionsItem>
</extensionItems>
```

to the following:

```
<ODEventNotificationExtraField>
<callCode> 1</callCode>
<callbackType> All </callbackType>
<callbackEmail> me@mine.org </callbackEmail>
</ODEventNotificationExtraField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stylesheet produces the desired result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="extensionItems">
        <ODEventNotificationExtraField>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ODEventNotificationExtraField>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="extensionsItem">
        <xsl:element name="{extName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="extValue"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the help I  also need help in doing the reverse that is transform the xml to name-value pair xml

Comment: @user1096618 - It's not easy to provide additional answers in the comments. Consider asking that as a new question.